# TeXstudio synctex not working in Windows

Tags: texstudio, windows

I just set up TeXstudio on Windows. Before, I was using it installed on WSL.

I am watching the same document (same build) in both installations, on the WSL TeXstudio synctex is working, on Windows not at all.
Hence, it cannot be an issue with the synctex file I believe but rather with TeXstudio itself. I am using the internal viewer in both cases.

Windows 11, TeXstudio 4.5.2 (git 4.5.2)
WSL: Debian 11, TeXstudio 3.0.4 (Build: 3.0.4+ds-1)
TeXlive 2023 on WSL for both editors

Maybe someone has an idea...
Thanks already,
Erik

---

PS: Just tested it with SumatraPDF on Windows, there it is working as well.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The issue lies in the compilation on WSL and viewing on Windows. In the synctex file, linux pathes are given which cannot be interpreted by programs running on Windows. Only option beside installing TeXlive on Windows seems to edit the synctex file after compilation with an automated script...